# Regex find and replace: delete everything *except* match

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm using Notepad++ to remove everything from HTML except an id matching ('idxxxxxx'). Here's (part of) the HTML:

```
{
    href : "/id123456",
    title : "Book 1",
    year : "2013",
},
                {
    href : "/id234567",
    title : "Book 2",
    year : "2014",
},
{
    href : "/id345678",
    title : "Book 3",
    year : "2015",
}
```

This regex isn't behaving as expected:

`[^id\d{6}]`

Rather than leaving all matching 'idxxxxxx's, it's also leaving *parts* of it: sequences of numbers, *any* instance of 'id', no necessarily followed by 6 digits etc.

Comment: That isn't HTML. It appears to be JSON.

Comment: Yes, of course :-)

Comment: what you are using is character class which is causing the problem..It can match only single character

Comment: Try `(?s)"/(id\d+)"|.` and replace with `$1\n`. Then just remove empty lines.

Comment: That's going to be a lot of newlines Wictor.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a branch reset.

Find `(?s)(?|.*?(id\d{6})|.*())`
Replace `$1`

```
 (?s)                   # Dot-all
 (?|                    # Branch Reset
      .*? 
      ( id \d{6} )           # (1)
   |  
      .* 
      ( )                    # (1)
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(?s).*?(id\d{6})|(?!id\d{6}).*$
```

It uses negation `!?`. `(?s)` for multiline modifier.

Your Regex is obviously wrong. `[^id\d{6}]` means any ONE character that is not `i`, `d`, `\`, `{`, `}`, or `6`.

Comment: Hmm. On replacing on that sample JSON, I'm left with three i's ("iii").

Comment: Sorry for the previous untested. I've updated the regex. This one works.

Answer (score 0):

```
Find what:     [\s\S]+?/(id\d+)|[\s\S]*
Replace with:  \1\n
```

Output:

```
id123456
id234567
id345678
```